# simple cryptograpic function

Tags: math, encryption, cryptography, numbers

There are these integers X, P, R and D

```
KX is known
UP, UR, UD are unknown (secret)
UD is much lower than KX*UP*UR
```

What I need is to write special function f(KX,UP,UR,UD) which will be known will meet these requirements:

1. From known results of f(KX,UP,UR,UD) for some KX is not possible to find results of f(KX+p,UP,UR,UD)
2. From known results of f(KX,UP+n,UR,UD) for n=0..100 is not possible to find result of f(KX,UP+101,UR,UD)

I was experimenting with something like

```
f=KX*UP*UR mod UD
```

but I have intuition, that it doesn't meet the second requirement.

Can such function exist?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the simplest solution I found is to simply compute MD5 hash of string made of concatenated integers. I think, that it is not reasonably possible to guess a hash what would be computed if I change one known part in unknown source string.

Comment: HMAC-SHA256 would be better.